# onFocus error in IE

Tags: javascript

Why do I get an error in IE for this line of code:

I used some stuff that works on the iPad but I was getting an error for the onFocus stuff before I even added it... here is the script that runs on focus:

function enterValue () {
                document.form1.itemQuantity.value = "";
            }

any idea's anyone???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

input type="<% =sType %>" class="inputbox" name="itemQuantity" min="1" max="99" step="1" value="<%=varMinQuantity%>" maxlength="2" size="2" onfocus="enterValue()" onclick="this.Focus();this.Select();"

Comment: that's the line.. it didn't take earlier

Answer (score 0):

You are doing too many things. onClick WILL focus all by itself, no need to focus and this.select is lowercase

```
<input type="<% =sType %>" class="inputbox" name="itemQuantity" min="1" max="99" step="1" value="<%=varMinQuantity%>" maxlength="2" size="2" onfocus="this.value=''" >
```

OR BETTER:

```
<input type="<% =sType %>" class="inputbox" name="itemQuantity" min="1" max="99" step="1" value="<%=varMinQuantity%>" maxlength="2" size="2" onfocus="this.select()" >
```

Comment: thanks... in the end I used the onfocus with he javascript entervalue() and it works great... forget the 1st rule of programming... Keep It Simple..

Comment: so calling a script that needs the form name of a form you cannot enter is better than not using form at all?